# Zend framework: Forms in modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, bootstrapping

What I want to do:

Create a number of modules with the forms folder inside them.

What I did:

Create a bootstrapper inside the module and added an _initAutoload function with the specific module name as namespace.

For instance, an admin module with the following bootstrapper:

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin_',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }

}
```

My question is:

Is this the correct way of doing what I want? - I tried it without having the admin bootstrapper, but it couldn't find my form, until I added the bootstrapper.

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 11):

The autoloader is automatically set up for each module bootstrap. You don't need to configure it manually.

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

is all you need.

Then put your forms in `/application/modules/admin/forms/`.

```
Admin_Form_Myform extends Zend_Form {...}
```

For your custom resources, customize resourceAutoloader:

```
   class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap 
   {
        public function _initAuloload() 
        {
             $resourceLoader = $this->_resourceAuloloader;
             // var_dump($resourceLoader);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Remember to add also in your apllication.ini

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

**resources.modules = ""**

Comment: @Samuele - can you please provide some links to resouces which describe the application.ini file in zend framework